# Mostrar hint quando componente receber foco

Tags: delphi

Como mostrar o hint de um TEdit quando ele receber foco, sem o mouse estar em cima do mesmo? Não coloquei código pois não tenho a minima ideia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trabalhe o seguinte código no evento `OnEnter` do(s) `TEdit`(s) desejado:

Crie as variáveis necessárias:

```
var
    Origin : TPoint; // Receberá a origem do Form na tela
    HintWindow : THintWindow; // Objeto Hint do delphi
    Hint : String; // Receberá a Hint do Edit
    EditL, EditT, EditR, EditB : Integer; // Parâmetros do retângulo da Hint
```

Defina os valores das variáveis:

```
Origin := ClientToScreen(Point(0,0)); //Origem do Form na tela
Hint := (Sender as TControl).Hint;  //Atribua a Hint do Edit
```

Calcule as posições para o retângulo da Hint:

```
EditL := Origin.X + (Sender as TControl).Left + 20;
EditT := Origin.Y + (Sender as TControl).Top - 12;
EditR := EditL + Length(Hint) * 9; 
EditB := EditT + 18;
```

Crie uma novo objeto Hint; mostre-o no retângulo calculado na linha anterior:

```
HintWindow := THintWindow.Create(nil);
HintWindow.ActivateHint( Rect(EditL, EditT, EditR, EditB), Hint );
```

No momento em que quiser liberar a Hint apenas use `HintWindow.Free`.

Sugiro que a libere no evento `OnExit` do Edit ou utilizando um Timer de 5 à 8 segundos para um efeito tradicional do Windows.

Comment: Tu acha que funciona para um TcxDBTextEdit da devexpress? Ele tem a propriedade ClientToScreen.

Comment: Verifique se ele é descendente de `TControl` e _voila_.

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra forma de fazer isto, que também trabalha em cima dos eventos, é criar a tua própria janela de sugestão com a [classe `THintWindow`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_THintWindow.html) como sugere [este artigo](http://users.atw.hu/delphicikk/listaz.php?id=161&oldal=37).

1. Defina as seguintes variáveis:

   ```
   FActive: boolean;
   FHint: THintWindow;
   ```

   **Atualização**: Abaixo da clausula `Uses` defina a constante:

   ```
   Uses
   //....

   Const
     UM_EXITPROC = WM_USER + 42;
   ```
2. Utilize o método abaixo para desativar a janela de sugestão:

   ```
   procedure DesativarSugestao;
   begin
     FActive := false;
     if Assigned(FHint) then
       begin
         FHint.ReleaseHandle;
         FHint.Free;
         FHint := nil;
       end;
   end;
   ```
3. Utilize o método abaixo para receber as mensagens de cliques do botão direito e esquerdo do mouse:

   ```
   procedure AppMessage(var AMessage: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
   begin
     if (AMessage.Message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) or (AMessage.Message = WM_RBUTTONDOWN) then
       if Assigned(FHint) and FHint.Visible then
         DesativarSugestao;
   end;
   ```
4. Método responsável por exibir a caixa de sugestão:

   ```
   procedure mostrarSugestao(Sender: TObject);
   Var
      P: TPoint;
      R: TRect;
      Sugestao: string;
   begin
     if Assigned(FHint) and FActive then
        Exit;
     P.X := (Sender As TEdit).Left;
     P.Y := (Sender As TEdit).Top - 24;
     with R do
       begin
         topLeft := ClientToScreen(P);
         Right := Left + 150;
         Bottom := Top + 18;
       end;

     Sugestao := 'A sugestão é...'; // Ou (Sender As TEdit).Text
     FHint := THintWindow.Create(Self);
     FHint.ActivateHint(R, Sugestao);
     FActive := True;
     PostMessage(Handle, UM_EXITPROC, 0, 0);
   end;
   ```
5. No evento `OnEnter` do `Edit` faça:

   ```
   procedure Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     if not Assigned(FHint) and FActive = False then
       mostrarSugestao(Sender);
   end;
   ```
6. No evento `OnExit` do `Edit` faça:

   ```
   procedure Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     if Assigned(FHint) and FActive then
       DesativarSugestao;
   end;
   ```
7. No evento `OnKeyPress` do `Edit` faça:

   ```
   procedure Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
   begin
     if Assigned(FHint) and FActive then
       DesativarSugestao;
   end;
   ```
8. No evento `OnMouseEnter` faça:

   ```
   procedure Edit1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     if not Assigned(FHint) and FActive = False then
       mostrarSugestao(Sender);
   end;
   ```
9. No evento `OnMouseLeave` faça:

   ```
   procedure Edit1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     if Assigned(FHint) and FActive then
       DesativarSugestao;
   end;
   ```
10. No evento `OnClick` do `Edit` faça:

    ```
    procedure TForm1.Edit1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      if Assigned(FHint) and FActive then
        DesativarSugestao;
    end;
    ```
11. No evento `OnCreate` do formulário faça:

    ```
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Application.OnMessage := AppMessage;
    end;
    ```

O resultado deverá ser semelhante a isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, talvez seja até melhor para mim já que uso outro tipo de TEdit. Obrigado.

Comment: @Artur_Indio Fico feliz em ajudar, editei a resposta, tinha esquecido de citar uma constante necessária.